# Repositories public by default

Tags: gitlab, gitorious

I installed GitLab and it seems that all repositories are private by default (the creator has to add all the developers to the project in order to share the code). I'd really like for all the repositories to be shown (and cloneable) by all the logged in users. Can gitourious do this?

Answer (score 0):

For allowing access for all users, you could add a rule directly in the [`gitolite.conf`](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/admin.html#conf) of the `gitolite-admin` repo (used by GitLab)

```
repo repo1
    R = @all
repo repo2
    R = @all
...
```

`R = @all` will allow read access (and clone) for all users.

---

[Issue 260](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/260) mentions that public clone is implemented for GitLab: those are [Projects with read-only access](https://gitlab.com/public).

That seems to have been introduced fairly recently (less than 3 weeks ago):

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\gitlabhq>git log --all-match --grep=public --grep=clone
commit b6da734824d0c74ef5bb4b784d404144c76d75f4
Merge: eff6d3c 80b8921
Author: Dmitriy Zaporozhets <dmitriy.zaporozhets@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 14 10:13:02 2013 -0800

    Merge pull request #2584 from jasl8r/public-grack-clone

    Public HTTP clones and remove auth request for public projects

commit 80b8921a9a0adb60c7eb8edeaf195d9dc2530cb9
Author: Jeremy Slater <jeremy.slater@nuance.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 14 09:46:55 2013 -0500

    Public HTTP clones and remove auth request for public projects
```

So you can see the new code at [commit 80b8921](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/80b8921a9a0ad) and [commit b6da734](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/b6da734824d0c7).

Comment: From what I can tell this allows unauthenticated users to look at the repository... not quite what I was after. I'd like all authenticated users to be able to look at all the other users and their repositories (and everyone's repositories to come up in search). Just like public repositories in GitHub.

Comment: @zoran119 ok, I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an 'Everyone' group with 'Guest' permissions, and add every repository to that group. Kind of a pain, especially if you have tons of repos, but it works.